# FWLSE3030E: The runtime "mfp" does not exist in the MobileFirst administration database. The database may be corrupted

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-cli, websphere-traditional

After installing and configuring MobileFirst 8 on WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.10, RedHat Linux 7.3, I am getting error

> FWLSE3030E: The runtime "mfp" does not exist in the MobileFirst administration database. The database may be corrupted.

I am using WebSphere SDK 1.7 with FP40

I have checked the Database, and all tables are present.

---

In the SystemOut.log, I am getting exceptions and it is as below:

> com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.util.exceptions.SystemException: FWLSE3002E: The resource is not found.

---

[SystemOut.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6mcb20o840vpfkt/SystemOut.log?dl=0)

---

**Edit1:** I have installed MobileFirst 8 using Command line, and configured it using Ant task.

**Edit2:** WAS Full profile deployed applications.
[image: Deployed Application]

Comment: You only mention what you did but not what you followed. It is more than likely that your server.xml is misconfigured or that you did not deploy all required resources. If the runtime "mfp" is missing then it's either missing as a .war file or the server.xml is not pointing to the correct place... Please edit the question and provide the full log file as well as the server.xml file.

Comment: @IdanAdar, I have deployed all the necessary resources. Where is server.xml file when I have deployed MobileFirst on WAS?

Comment: server.xml is a standard Liberty file. It is typically found under usr/servers/your-server-folder/

Comment: I think there is some understanding gap, I have installed MobileFirst on WAS Network Deployment Profile, not in Liberty profile.

Comment: @IdanAdar I have attached SystemOut.log

Comment: Which instructions did you follow? Have you read thoroughly this document? https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/installation-configuration/production/appserver/

Comment: I have followed all of the instruction from there thoroughly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symptom you're seeing seems like an open issue that is being tracked as APAR PI71317.  Please open a PMR and mention this APAR number; we can give you a test fix to try to help us confirm that it is indeed this issue.

Comment: Is there any web link from where I can see the details regarding this APAR?

Comment: There is no web link yet, as this APAR is relatively new and is still in progress.  When the APAR becomes available on the web, you will be able to see it at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI71317, but it's not there just yet.

Comment: The information about APAR PI71317 is now available at the URL I mentioned in my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

first: go to the WAS ND JDBC data sources section and choose the MFP data source and press the "test connection" button.
look carefully at the DSN definition and make sure you can browse that same DB with other tool and ensure the schema and tables exist.
bare in mind: in WAS ND there should be two entries : one for runtime DB and one for MFP admin DB.

Comment: I am seeing two JDBC providers. 1] MobileFirst JDBC Provider 2] MobileFirst administration JDBC Provider.

I have checked data sources and test connection is successful. Also I am able to connect to DB with other tools like Dbeaver.